# SQL group by not giving expected result, multiple lines instead of one

Tags: sql

Hi I have this piece of code

```sql
SELECT
    anonymous_id,
    SUM(plan_cost) as plan_cost,
    CAST(sent_at AS DATE) as date,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY anonymous_id) as ocurrences

FROM
    "****-348311.****_prod.purchase"

GROUP BY
    anonymous_id,
    sent_at

ORDER BY
    date asc;
```

the result that I am getting is close to what I want, but when I have more than 1 of the same anonymous_id for the same day I get 2 rows and I need only 1 row with the unique anonymous_id, the sum of the plan_cost for that day, and the count of rows for that anonymous_id

this is what I am getting

| anonymous_id | plan_cost | date | ocurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5ac5ff46-ea1c-4f00-891e-fd74e618588f | 294.42 | 2023-05-10 | 2 |
| 5ac5ff46-ea1c-4f00-891e-fd74e618588f | 346.48 | 2023-05-10 | 2 |

this is what I need

| anonymous_id | plan_cost | date | ocurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5ac5ff46-ea1c-4f00-891e-fd74e618588f | 640.9 | 2023-05-10 | 2 |

Comment: Could you please explain why you do not use COUNT(*) AS ocurrences

Comment: At a guess it's because `sent_at` is *not* a date hence why you're casting it; It probably has *date and time* so you are seeing two rows for two different times - group by `CAST(sent_at AS DATE)` also

Comment: You say you want `plan_cost = 640.9` - not `640.90`? That looks like you're using `float` or `real` for `plan_cost` instead of a proper `decimal` (or even `money`) type - if so, you should fix that first, because using `float` for currency/monetary amounts is a huge cause of bugs.

Comment: @Stu when I try your suggestion I  get an error on the sent_at at the top "SELECT list expression references column sent_at which is neither grouped nor aggregated at"

Comment: @Dai I changed the top part for `SUM(CAST(plan_cost as decimal))` and i get the same result

Comment: @JuanLozano I wasn't suggesting you use `CAST` in your query - I'm talking about the underlying `TABLE` column. Can you share your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @Dai, I dont create the table it is already created for me, but looking at the schema it is a float

Comment: @JuanLozano You should find whoever is responsible for making that column `float` and then _make them suffer_ for their sins.

Comment: The original problem has already been described. You need to group on `cast(sent_at as date)` rather than the value with a time component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Stu's speculation that your `sent_at` column is likely the cause, as it doesn't look like it's a `date` column, but a `datetime`/`datetime2`/etc column, so doing `GROUP BY` with it (i.e. `GROUP BY anonymous_id, sent_at`) won't give you useful results: you need to `GROUP BY` the `date`-only part of `sent_at`:

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT
    -- GROUP BY:
    anonymous_id,
    CAST( sent_at AS date )                     AS sent_at_date,

    -- Aggregates:
    SUM( plan_cost )                            AS plan_cost,
    COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY anonymous_id ) AS ocurrences

FROM
    "****-348311.****_prod.purchase"

GROUP BY
    anonymous_id,
    CAST( sent_at AS date )

ORDER BY
    sent_at_date,
    anonymous_id;
```

---

- I added `anonymous_id` to your `ORDER BY` clause to ensure consistent results (otherwise re-running your query *might* return rows in different orders): when using `ORDER BY` you should always specify sufficient columns to ensure consistent ordering after your top-level sorting (using a row's key should be sufficient).

Comment: I tried your solution but the function CONVERT didnt work, I am using the SQL editor inside Big Query, but I saw you edited my code, that table formating is super cool, ill start using it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was far simple that I expected, I am using SQL inside of GCP so I dont know if it is because of that.  I just used the alias of the CAST sent_at and it worked

```
SELECT 
anonymous_id, SUM(CAST(plan_cost as decimal)) as plan_cost, CAST(sent_at AS DATE) as date,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY anonymous_id) as ocurrences
FROM 
"****-348311.****_prod.purchase"
GROUP BY 
anonymous_id, date
ORDER BY 
date asc;
```